# DNS Error but Favicon Loads

Tags: html, web, dns, server

Currently migrating a site from a personal VPS to a dedicated server with a new (sub)domain name. There is no DNS entry for the site (and nslookup returns NXDOMAIN), but the favicon is loading - how is that possible?

**Chrome's DNS Error:**
This site can’t be reached
[hidden]’s server DNS address could not be found.
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

**nslookup**:
** server can't find [hidden]: NXDOMAIN

Any ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your browser caches favicons on the domain name rather than IP, so it is able to display the icon even though the site has been migrated.